# Python - splitting a list then loop through to find an ip address

Tags: python

I'm required to analyse a system log. I've been told that I should split a list and then iterate through it to find an ip address. This is a small part of the log. There are duplicate entries therefore I must only take notice of the lines which contain the words "Failed password for from root".

```
Jan 10 09:32:07 j4-be03 sshd[3876]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.241.173.35  user=root
Jan 10 09:32:09 j4-be03 sshd[3876]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 47084 ssh2
Jan 10 09:32:17 j4-be03 sshd[3879]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.241.173.35  user=root
Jan 10 09:32:19 j4-be03 sshd[3879]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 47901 ssh2
Jan 10 09:32:26 j4-be03 sshd[3881]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.241.173.35  user=root
Jan 10 09:32:29 j4-be03 sshd[3881]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 48652 ssh2
```

Here is my code so far, bit of psuedo code aswell.

```
f=open('auth','r')
count=0 
for line in f:
    if "failed password for root from" in line:
count +=1
if count>=13:
    take the ip address, remove duplicates and print the address
```

If there are 13 or more attempts from one ip address this address must be added to a file. I understand how to write a new file, however if possible a small example would be handy. I am familiar with .append

Comment: No I do not have experience with regular expressions sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easier to use `re`:

```
re_ips = r'Failed password for (?:root|invalid user\s?.*) from ((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) '
```

This will get you all the IP addresses from the relevant lines. Here's an example of how to use this regex to print  the IPs that recur 13 or more times to the file `bad_ips.log`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

ip_freq = defaultdict(int)
with open("auth", "r") as fh:
    for match in re.finditer(r'Failed password for (?:root|invalid user\s?.*) from ((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) ', fh.read()):
        ip_freq[match.group(1)] += 1

with open("bad_ips.log", "w") as fh:
    for ip, n in ip_freq.iteritems():
        if n>=13:
            print >>fh, ip
```

**edit:** updated regex per your new request.

**edit2:** updated regex again to match correctly `invalid user xxxx` in log file.

**edit3:** tidied up example

Comment: how would i then display the results?

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you very much. just a slight add-on before I leave you in peace. I have a few more ips to check through, however they begin with "Failed password for invalid user". Where would it make sense to add this in to the code?

Comment: Do you want to tally the 'invalid user' IPs together with the 'root' IPs or do you want separate tallies?

Comment: would it be possible to tally them all together please?

Comment: That's the easier way :) just change the regex to `ip_list = re.findall(r'Failed password for (?:root|invalid user) from ((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) '`

Comment: After entering the new regex it keeps waiting for input and won't exit the loop no matter how many times I press enter

Comment: The code in my comment got cut off; it should continue: `, fh.read())`. Anyway, see the edit to the example in my post for how to incorporate this updated regex.

Comment: It just shows the one ip address. I've gone through the log and there are a few more with more than 13 attempts. If I pastebin it here would you be able to look through it and see if you can figure it out? I think it's just something to do with the "password from" bit but the ip addresses have different lengths so maybe its the regex? http://pastebin.com/Aaa9fYYJ. I've just noticed there are little words between the from parts on the log such as "Failed password for invalid user CYRUS from" would I need to include the "cyrus" part aswell? there's a few others such as virus too

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much! I don't suppose you'd be able to quickly tell me exactly what the regex is doing? I've never used them before in Python you see. Mainly the ((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) part and user\s?.*) this bit, if you could please.

Comment: You can find everything you need to know to understand the regex here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import re 
with open('auth', 'r') as f:
    ip_list = re.findall(r'Failed password for root from (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', f.read()))
    thirteen_plus = [i for i in set(ip_list) if ip_list.count(i) >= 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import re
f = open('auth', 'r')
ip_list = re.findall(r'Failed password for root from (.*?)\s', f.read())
clean_list = [ip for ip in set(ip_list) if ip_list.count(ip) > 13]
```

There you get `clean_list` which contains only IPs that are repeated more than 13 times in `auth`.

Comment: This is good, however it is only displaying one ip address when i print clean_list. There should be a few other address. any ideas?

Comment: Check out what are you getting in `ip_list` and `set(ip_list)`. There might be something I overlook. I just tested it with the sample log lines you provided. Also, are you sure you have more than one IP which repeats more than 13 times?

Comment: in ip_list i am getting root and invalid repeated a lot of times. in set(ip_list) i am getting set(['root', 'invalid']) yeah there's four or five ips which should show up

Comment: Then there's something that is not working with the regex. When I tested with your sample log lines it worked. Check if there's any difference there and try to fix the regexp if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can get that IP address from there just by taking the -4th element of the list returned by `split()`. To count the occurrences of certain addresses, you can either add them to a list and use its `count()` method or create some kind of counting dictionary (there are handy classes designed fot it, too, but you can do with a regular dict).

```
ip_count = {}
for line in open("auth"):
    if "Failed password for root from" in line:
        ip = line.split()[-4]
        if ip in ip_count:
            ip_count[ip] += 1
        else:
            ip_count[ip] = 1
```

Then you analyze the dict and maybe write the frequently encountered IPs to a file:

```
out = open("frequent.ips", 'w')
for ip in ip_count:
    if ip_count[ip] > 13:
        out.write("%s: %d attempts.\n" % (ip, ip_count[ip]))
```

Comment: everything went well besides the end )). I recieved a syntax error saying: EOL while scanning string literal. The brackets seem fine to me though. Two to close off?

Comment: What's in `ip_count` and in the output file?

Comment: ip_count contains {'213.251.192.26': 13, '218.241.173.35': 15, '89.249.209.92': 13} nothing is in the output file. i guess this is because I cannot complete the write function at the bottom

Comment: I don't really get it yet, but one thing I can say is that, if it worked, only one IP would be in the output - the one that's encountered 15 times. This is to address your comment to the other answer that you expect several IPs there.

Comment: I changed \n" to //n" and there is no longer a syntax error. However, there is still nothing being written to the file

Comment: Make sure you reload the file, also you probably shoud close the file with `out.close()` at the very end.